# how to add choices in select after page load in symfony2

Tags: jquery, forms, symfony

After loading a page the select field is completed dinamically with jquery but the post data is not loaded in $form->getData(). After some search, the option is to add a hidden field and add the value with javascript. I'd like to know if exist another option.

This is the action:

```
 $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('country','file')
    ->add('admcod2','file')
    ->add('isocountry', 'choice', array('empty_value' => 'select country'))
    ->add('iso','hidden')
    ->getForm();
```

The choice is filled with jquery

```
$("#form_isocountry").jeoCountrySelect({
    callback: function () {
    $("#form_isocountry").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});

//this add the value to a hidden field... 
$("#form_isocountry").change(function() {
    $("#form_iso").val($("#form_isocountry").val());
})
```

So symfony do not recognice the options loaded in dinamic selects. var_dump($form->getData()) show the hidden field filled but not the select field.

Thanks.

Comment: Argggg. Ok, I see. I will add 'programmatically' choices with Services_GeoNames(Pear) in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `choice` is not the right type of field for this use case, because from the form field perspective, list of possible choices is empty. Therefore submitted value will never be valid (except when empty).

I can suggest you to either use `hidden` as type of this field or specify list of choices to your form field with `choice` type .

Answer (score 0):

I've used `ChoiceType` fields this way. I think it's the logical choice. The main issue with it (and the default `EntityToIdTransformer` or `EntityChoiceList`) is that it hydrates every possible option in order to select one, which is overkill in some cases. You'll probably need to write your own transformer to prevent that. I use AJAX to load data into selects after the page has loaded. It makes the pages smaller, speeds up page processing time and lets me cache each set of options more precisely.

This is for Symfony 2.0. It works fine and we've put a bunch of Chosen fields on one page with 4000+ options in them (although it only creates the Chosen elements when the user interacts with the widget). Now the limitation is browser memory.

**ContactEntityType**

```
class ContactEntityType extends AbstractType {    
    public function __construct(EntityManager $em) {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options) 
    {
        $repository = $this->em->getRepository('AcmeContactsBundle:Contact');
        $builder->prependClientTransformer(new ContactToIdTransformer($repository));
    }

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form)
    {
        $contact = $form->getData();

        if($contact instanceof \Acme\ContactsBundle\Entity\Contact) {
            $view->set('choices', array($contact->getId() => $contact->getName()));
        }
    }

    public function getParent(array $options) {
        return 'choice';
    }
}
```

**ContactToIdTransformer**

This is a variation on the built-in `EntityToIdTransformer`.

```
...
class ContactToIdTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    private $repository;

    public function __construct(EntityRepository $repository)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }

    public function transform($entity)
    {            
        if (null === $entity || '' === $entity) {
            return null;
        }

        if (!is_object($entity)) {
            throw new UnexpectedTypeException($entity, 'object');
        }

        if ($entity instanceof Collection) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Expected an object, but got a collection. Did you forget to pass "multiple=true" to an entity field?');
        }

        return $entity->getId();
    }

    public function reverseTransform($key)
    {
        if ('' === $key || null === $key) {
            return null;
        }

        if (!is_numeric($key)) {
            throw new UnexpectedTypeException($key, 'numeric');
        }

        if (!($entity = $this->repository->find($key))) {
            throw new TransformationFailedException(sprintf('The entity with key "%s" could not be found', $key));
        }
        return $entity;
    }
}
```